# Obtener un camino mínimo en una matriz de pesos en R

Tags: r, matrices

Es la primera vez que pregunto pero sí que me he visto otras respuestas y me habéis ayudado mucho. Gracias.
Tengo un problema a la hora de encontrar el camino mínimo que recorra todos los vértices de un grafo completo. Para ello tengo una matriz de pesos (i,j), donde peso[i,j] me indica el peso de ir del vértice i al vértice j.
He hecho lo siguiente:

Obtengo el índice donde se encuentra el mínimo con la función which.min(), me guardo la fila y la columna, para que no lo vuelva a seleccionar pongo todos los valores a Inf.
Esto lo hago dentro de un bucle para que se vaya llenando a infinitos y siempre encuentre el menor.
Dentro del bucle vuelvo a buscar el índice con el valor mínimo y me devuelve el mismo que el anterior aunque la matriz ha sido modificada, no sé como conseguir que me vuelva a encontrar otro mínimo.
El camino siempre es el primer vértice al segundo con peso mínimo y se queda ahí.

Adjunto la parte de código donde lo realizo:

```
for(i in 1:30)
{
    x=which.min(pesos) #Elegimos el mínimo de la matriz y nos guardamos su índice
    fila=x/30
    fila=trunc(fila)+1 #Nos quedamos con la fila
    columna=x%%30 #Nos quedamos con la columna
    #El valor de esa fila y esa columna será infinito
    pesos[fila,]=Inf
    if(columna==0) columna=30
   pesos[,columna]=Inf
   camino=cbind(camino,columna)#me guardo el nodo destino
 }
```

Muchas gracias